# Dynamically obtain the list of columns for INSERT/UPDATE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, triggers, information-schema

I have two MySQL databases: D1 and D2 belonging to two different versions of the same project. The schemas are slightly different, and the difference will grow. The requirement is to keep certain tables automatically synchronised one way D1→D2 on matching columns. The challenge is that the list of matching columns will be changing.

Currently I am doing it with triggers in D1 on create/update/delete that write to D2. The triggers are generated/updated with a *non-SQL* script that finds out the list of matching columns by reading `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. The inconvenience is that the script needs to be re-run manually every time a change is made to the D2's schema that will affect the list of matching columns. If I forget to re-run the script, the triggers in D1 will fail when they try to update/insert a column in D2 that does not exist anymore.

So, the question is: is it possible / how to write INSERT/UPDATE statements where the list of columns is variable and dynamically retrieved from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: This *sounds* like a bad idea

Comment: What would be a better idea then? @Strawberry

Comment: I'm not sure, but as a first step, see replication